# $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to $X_1\times\cdots\times X_t$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, general-linear-group

Since I still don’t know the answer, I’ve also asked it on [math.overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360865/g-fg-is-isomorphic-to-x-1-times-cdots-times-x-t).

I saw a remark in an [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25315/how-is-a-group-made-up-of-simple-groups/55941#55941) that

> $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a group of the form $X_1 \times \ldots \times X_t,$ where each $X_i$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a completely reducible solvable subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n_i,p_i)$ for some integer $n_i$ and prime $p_i$.

**Before I ask my question, I need to fill in some details**.

It is well-known that for a finite solvable group $G$, [$G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a *subgroup* of ${\rm Out}(F(G))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3661581/784417). Let $p_i(i=1,\cdots, t)$ be all the prime divisors of $|G|$. It follows that $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Out}(O_{p_1}(G))\times\cdots\times{\rm Out}(O_{p_t}(G))$.

If $\Phi(G)=1$, then [$\Phi(O_{p_i}(G))\le\Phi(G)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3670439/784417) for each $p_i$ dividing $|G|$. It follows that each $O_{p_i}(G)$ is elementary abelian, namely there exists a positive integer $n_i$ such that $O_{p_i}(G)=C_{p_i}^{n_i}$. Since we can see elementary abelian groups as vector spaces, ${\rm Aut}(O_{p_i}(G))\cong{\rm GL}_{n_i}(\mathbb{F}_{p_i})$. In addition, since $O_{p_i}(G)$ is abelian, ${\rm Inn}(O_{p_i}(G))$ is trivial and hence ${\rm Out}(O_{p_i}(G))\cong {\rm Aut}(O_{p_i}(G))\cong{\rm GL}_{n_i}(\mathbb{F}_{p_i})$. Then we know that $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm GL}_{n_1}(\mathbb{F}_{p_1})\times\cdots\times{\rm GL}_{n_t}(\mathbb{F}_{p_t})$.

If $\Phi(G)\neq 1$, we still can know that [$\Phi(G/\Phi(G))$ is trivial](https://mathoverflow.net/a/360306/157585). Since $G$ is solvable, we have $\Phi(G)\subseteq F(G)$ and $F(G)/\Phi(G)=F(G/\Phi(G))$. By the third isomorphism theorem,
$$G/F(G)\cong G/\Phi(G)\big/F(G)/\Phi(G)= G/F(G)\cong G/\Phi(G)\big/F(G/\Phi(G))
.$$Hence we can get a similar conclusion.

**My question is:** By the reasoning above, I can only know that $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a *subgroup* of ${\rm GL}_{n_1}(\mathbb{F}_{p_1})\times\cdots\times{\rm GL}_{n_t}(\mathbb{F}_{p_t})$. In general, if $A$ is a subgroup of $A_1\times\cdots\times A_t$, we cannot say $A$ is of the form $X_1\times\cdots\times X_t$, where $X_i$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_i$. But here each $X_i$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n_i,p_i)$. I want to know what was different in this specific case.

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the group $G$ is solvable

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes. In my linked posts they were all assumed to be solvable. I’ve edited my question to clarify that. Did I miss anything helpful for my question when $G$ is solvable?

Comment: As stated, the assertion is trivially true for every finite solvable group, because we can just choose a single prime $p_1=p$ that does not divide $|G|$  (so every subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,p)$ is completely reducible). Perhaps the $p_i$ are intended to be the primes dividing $|F(G)|$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your comment. I’m not familiar with the term “completely reducible”. Could you please tell me how it helps me with this question?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, $p_i$ are intended to be the primes dividing $|F(G)|$, because $p_i$ are all prime divisors of $|G|$, and $|G|$ and $|F(G)|$ have exactly the same set of prime divisors.

Comment: You should edit the question to include all of the assumptions.

Comment: @DerekHolt I’ve just edited my question and I think all the assumptions are included now.

Comment: I don't see any edits. The quoted remark  at the top of your post is only true if $G$ is solvable, and in that case, as I explained before, it is trivially true.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360865/g-fg-is-isomorphic-to-x-1-times-cdots-times-x-t

Comment: The original answer was slightly misstated: It should have said that $G/F(G)$ is A SUBGROUP OF a group of the form $X_1 \times X_2 \times \ldots X_t$, where each $X_i$ is a completely reducible subgroup of …...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have said in comments, it is not hard to prove the remark as stated.

But here is a stronger statement that is definitely not true.

Let $G$ be solvable and suppose that $F(G)$ is a direct product of elementary abelian groups $C_{p_i}^{n_i}$ for fprimes $p_1,\ldots,p_t$. Then $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a direct product $X_1 \times \cdots \times X_t$, where $X_i$ is isomorphic to a solvable completely reducible subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n_i,p_i)$.

That is not true. I can construct an example in which $F(G) = C_2^2 \times C_5^2$. and $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of index $2$ in$X_1 \times X_2$ with $X_1 \cong X_2 \cong S_3$, but $G/F(G)$ is indecomposable and is not itself isomorphic to $X_1 \times X_2$ for any $X_1 \le {\rm GL}(2,2)$ and $X_2 \le {\rm GL}(2,5)$.

Comment: Yes, there was a slip in the original answer: It should have said that $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to A SUBGROUP OF a group of the form $X_1 \times X_2 \times \ldots \times X_t $, where each $X_i$ is a completely reducible solvable subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n_i,p_i)$